# How the union of a bound series of integers converges to all integers for cases of all orders.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

For the series $S_n = \{-n, \cdots, n \}^d$ I would like to show the union of all such sets converge to $\mathbb{Z}^d$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. That is to said, how can I prove:

$$\bigcup_{n \geq 1} S_n = \mathbb{Z}^d$$